# Checking status of message insert to Azure Queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-account

I have 1 problem about Azure Queue. After insert 1 message to Azure Queue, how can I check this message have been inserted successful or not in my code (.net)?

My solution is checking number of message already storage in queue and check again after insert new message queue. I try to find another solution. Thank for helping me

Comment: Do you use the SDK to send information? If so, the return value should be a response. It can tell you directly whether the transmission is successful.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue lib for sending message to Queue and function is void so i can't get response. Sorry if I  misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The design of method 'AddMessageAsync' in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue` is like this:

`public virtual Task AddMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message);`

It returns nothing, so you have two ways:

The first one is like you says, get the number of the messages in queue and check after Add message.

The second one is put the logic in the try-catch, return exception if add message not success.

**Original Answer:**

Have a look of this API reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient.sendmessage?view=azure-dotnet

The return type of the sendmessage method is response, so I think you don't need to get the number of the messages. Just check the response status is OK.

Comment: yah, I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue lib for insert message to queue and my function is AddMessageAsync() (void) so i can't get this respone.

Comment: @haipham Since this method does not return any information, I think you have two methods. The first, as you said, checks the number of messages in the queue before and after sending. The second is to put the sending logic into try-catch, if the sending is unsuccessful, an exception can be thrown.

Comment: yah, that a good idea, I forgot that if not success it can thrown an exception. Let me try, thank for supporting me <3